# Assign array of image elements to DOM ids

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom

I have an array of URIs that represent .png elements, e.g., "./img/diamond-red-solid-1.png".

I want to assign each element of the array "gameDeck[0], gameDeck[1], etc. to div ids in HTML. Do I need to identify the elements as = SRC.IMG?

```
var gameDeck[];
var gameBoardCards = function () {
    for (let cardArr of cardsToLoad)
    gameDeck.push("./img/" + cardArr + ".png");
}

gameBoardCards();

document.addEventListener('DOM Content Loaded', function () {
  gameDeck[0] = document.getElementById("card1");
  gameDeck[1] = document.getElementById("card2");
  etc.      
});
```

Comment: Your current code would populate an array of strings (representing paths to images), and then replace each one with a potential DOM node that doesn't use the string in any way. I doubt this is the intended behavior. Can you clarify what you actually want to accomplish?

Comment: What I want to have happen is to have each image appear in separate divs by ids.

Comment: Hi @mickeychcg I wrote an answer for you but now I'm second guessing my understanding of what you want. Are the divs with ids card1, card2 etc already in the DOM/HTML OR do you want to create the divs with ids card1 etc dynamically? if you let me know I can change it easy enough :)

Comment: Hi @sarah, I'm looking at your answer, so bear with me ;), but to answer your question, I've created the div placeholders in HTML with the ids card1, card2, and so forth. There are to be a dozen cards on the gameBoard surface that have been extracted from a deck of 81 cards, and those functions have been written.

Comment: @mickeychcg Oh I see. ok no probs. I will need to change the code slightly so bear with me :)

Comment: @mickeychcg I've just changed my answer there as I understand what you want better now :) Hope this helps :)

Comment: Something like a card game in raw HTML and JavaScript DOM manipulation is for raving lunatics. Use React or some other templating engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I'm understanding your question is that you would like to target the divs in your `HTML` with ids of card1, card2, card3... card12 etc.

You would like to insert an `img` tag into each of these divs with the `src` being the URIs of the gameDeck array.

The following code achieves this. I've tested it and it works fine. Hope it helps :)

```
 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  //iterate through the gameDeck array.
  for (let x = 0;x < gameDeck.length;x++){
    //create an img tag for each gameDeck element
    var imgElement = document.createElement("img"); 
    //set the source of the img tag to be the current gameDeck element (which will be a URI of a png file)
    imgElement.src = gameDeck[x];

    //target the div with id "card(x + 1)" 
    var cardID = "card" + (x + 1);
    var cardElement = document.getElementById(cardID);

    //append the img tag to the card element
    cardElement.appendChild(imgElement);   
  } 
  //log the HTML to the console to check it
  console.log(document.getElementById('body').innerHTML);
});
```

Comment: this works well, thank you! Lots more to get done on this, but I'm feeling a bit more confident. I may be posting more questions before the night ends. :-)

Comment: @mickeychcg That's good. glad its working for you :) Good luck with the rest. I will keep an eye out for more questions lol :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way that you can either insert images as background images, or as `<img />` elements into the `divs` you are referring to:

```html
<div id="card0" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;"></div>
<div id="card1" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;"></div>
```

```
let loadedImage = [];

function preloadImages(urls, allImagesLoadedCallback) {
  let loadedCounter = 0;
  let toBeLoadedNumber = urls.length;
  urls.forEach(function(url) {
    preloadImage(url, function() {
      loadedCounter++;
      console.log(`Number of loaded images: ${loadedCounter}`);
        if (loadedCounter == toBeLoadedNumber) {
          allImagesLoadedCallback();
        }
      });
    });

  function preloadImage(url, anImageLoadedCallback) {
    img = new Image();
    img.src = url;
    img.onload = anImageLoadedCallback;
    loadedImage.push(img);
  }
}

function gameBoardCards() {
  for (let i = 0; i < loadedImage.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById(`card${i}`).style.backgroundImage = `url('${loadedImage[i].src}')`;
    // document.getElementById(`card${i}`).appendChild(loadedImage[i]);
  }
}

preloadImages([
`https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/7d/Color_icon_green.svg/2000px-Color_icon_green.svg.png`,   `https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/ff/Solid_blue.svg/225px-Solid_blue.svg.png`
], function() {
    console.log(`all images were loaded`);
    gameBoardCards();
    // continue your code
});
```

It may seem like a bit much for what you are trying to accomplish, but I threw in a proper image-loading handler there. The `preloadImages` function will handle the loading of images, that way they are properly preloaded, and can render to the DOM. Often times, we try to use images before they are properly loaded, resulting in them sometimes not being displayed, despite no errors are being thrown.

The rest of the code is straight forward, in the `for` loop, it loops through the existing `divs` and you can either use the current active line `` document.getElementById(`card${i}`).style.backgroundImage = `url('${loadedImage[i].src}')`; `` to use the `loadedImage[i]` image `src` to load that as the `divs`'s background image. Or you can use the commented-out line directly below that `` document.getElementById(`card${i}`).appendChild(loadedImage[i]); `` to insert an `<img />` element into that div. Just use either one that works for you.

You can see the code in action in this [JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/samlegros/krhjvcs7/63/).

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks @Sam, I'm looking this over, and as a very novice coder, I'm not very fast.

Comment: My pleasure! Let me know if you have any questions and we can walk through it together.

Comment: this may be a bit more advanced for me, yes. If it's possible for you to walk me through it, I would absolutely appreciate it!

Comment: Take a look at this [updated JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/samlegros/ox8s10nm/). I've added some line-by-line comments explaining what each part does. I hope it helps :)